# Blank Firebase project makes connection to unexpected public database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase makes a connection to an unexpected public database on a brand new project. The template of the database where it connects looks like https://s-usc1c-nss-XXX.firebaseio.com, where XXX is a 3 digit number.

Connecting to the server listed in the connection above shows an insecure public database, e.g. https://s-usc1c-nss-204.firebaseio.com/.json

Is this normal behavior?

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.2.0",
    "firebase": "^7.14.4",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3"
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

That connection is part of Firebase's internal routing protocol, and is how the Firebase client determines what server/cluster your database is currently hosted on.

The client caches the server/cluster name that it gets back, so you should usually not see this lookup on each connection.

Comment: I discovered this when trying to filter outgoing connections. I assume there is no way to predict which 3 digit number it's going to connect to so I can add it to the rules?

Answer (score 0):

All Realtime Database instances are "public".  That's how cloud services work that must be reachable directly by client apps running anywhere on the internet.  Without a public service, the client would have no way to make the query.

If you need to secure the database from direct client access, you will need to [write security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) to determine who can read and write which locations in the database.